# Notepad++ Regex find line pattern but only replace one line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am new to regex.

I want to modify lines in a text file based on a particular pattern. I was able to write an expression to find the pattern but in the group of line that it returns I want to only replace one line and keep the rest as it is.

Here is an example:

```
Field1,
Field2,
Field3,
Field4,
Field5;
```

I used the following expression to find this group with my text file

```
.*.Field1,\r\n.*.\r\n.*.\r\n.*.Field4,
```

I want to only replace this line:

```
Field4
```

I am not sure how to write an expression that would keep the other line as they are.

Do you have any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer, by using () in the search field and \ in the replace field.

For instance, to do what I wanted to do I would have used the following:

- In the search field: `(.*.)\r\n(.*.)\r\n(.*.)\r\n(.*.)`
- In the replace field: `\1\r\n STRING TO BE CHANGED\r\n\3\r\n\4`

Comment: We don't really mind people finding out answers themselves, whether it's 5 minutes or 5 years later. Self-answers are considered good and acceptable when they can help everyone. In  a couple of days you should be able to accept your answer and thus mark this question as "complete".

Comment: This is a pretty vague answer. Could you expand your answer to explain how to use the capturing group? I.e., provide the pattern and the replacement expression you used.